# How manage ng-repeat inside?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display list of checkboxes, or some flags inside ng-repeat:

```
<div style='width:630px;' ng-repeat='item in shops'>
      // switch html here       
</div>
```

Basic idea is: I have '`$scope.shops`' array - main array, managing by `ng-repeat`, 20 objects inside array.

```
$scope.shops = [
{
   logo: '',
   address: '',
   city: ''
},
{
   logo: '',
   address: '',
   city: ''
},
....
]
```

I have another small array with similar objects '`$scope.checkForShops`'.
If object from '`$scope.checkForShops`' array available in '`$scope.shops`' I need to display extra html inside ng-repeat. Don't know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use the ng-show directive.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

This directive is passed an expression and will show the html if the expression evaluates to true. The expression should evaluate weather the element meets the criteria you specified within your ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If the length are the same and shop's index map to the other array's index, you can use **$index**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

You can simply nest another `ng-repeat` inside.

Here's a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jm6ffcdk/2/)